# Financial Inst - Model Role+Relationships b/w Person and Account

Tags: mysql, database-design, erd

A `Person` can be on one-or-more `Accounts`. For each `Account` a `Person` is on, `Person` has a certain *role* on that account i.e.

`Person 1` is *primary* on `Account 1`

`Person 1` is *joint* on `Account 2`

`Person 1` is *beneficiary* on `Account 3`

**Note:**
An `Account` only has 1 *primary* `Person`, but can have any number (0+) of *joint* or *beneficiary*

How should this be modeled? I at least forsee these tables:

```
Person
- person_id
- name
- dob
- address

Account
- account_id
- creation_date
```

I'm unclear on representing a many-to-many relationship between `Person` and `Account` while simultaneously capturing the *role* (primary, joint, beneficiary).

My idea: Have multiple *role Link* tables like so:

```
Link_Primary_Person_Account
- person_id
- account_id

Link_Joint_Person_Account
- person_id
- account_id

Link_Beneficiary_Person_Account
- person_id
- account_id
```

What do you think? What are other ways of doing this? This is all I can come up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Four tables will solve and normalize the data:

```
Person
- person_id
- name
- dob
- address

Account
- account_id
- creation_date

PersonAccountRole
- person_id (PK)
- account_id (PK)
- role_id
- etc...

Role
- role_id
- role_descrip
- etc...
```

Comment: with `(person_id, account_id)` the primary key.

Comment: ooh I like this... I'm gonna mull over this for a bit

Comment: @ypercube Well in my case it's a Data Vault (so I will be tracking changes over time) so I won't be putting a PK on `(person_id, account_id)` in `PersonAccountRole` as `(person_id, account_id)` can change, repeat, over time. There will be a surrogate PK to differentiate, and a time-stamp for when it occurred

Comment: @JohnM another issue: there is a *role* association between `Person` and `Account` -- but there's also an idea of *role* between `Person` and `Person` i.e. `Married to` or `Sibling` or `Parent`. With that in mind, I can't just name the table `Role` because there are different groups / meanings of roles -- do you suggest any naming conventions for this? Let me know if that's unclear

Comment: @mmcrae You could utilize the same approach and make a `PersontoPersonRole` table which contains the subject's ID, a relationship reference, and their relation's ID. In the `role` table you could have a `role_type` column to signify if it's a personal role or an account based one. Naming may depend on the scope more than anything else.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your input John!